# Supervisors in STORM

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-storm

I have a doubt in storm and here is goes:

Can multiple supervisors run on a single node? or is it the fact that we can run only one supervisor in one machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Principle, There should be 1 Supervisor daemon per 1 physical machine. Why ?

Answer : Nimbus receives heart beat of Supervisor daemon and try to restart it in case supervisor died, if nimbus failed permanently on restart attempt. Nimbus will assign that job to another Supervisor.
Imagine, two Supervisors going down same time as they are from same physical machine, poor fault tolerant !!

running two Supervisor daemons will also be waste of memory resources.

If you have very high memory machines simply increase number of workers by adding more ports in storm.yaml instead adding supervisor.slots.ports.

Comment: Hey, isn't increasing `supervisor.slots.ports` the same as increasing the number of ports in `storm.yaml`? ie: you have to use `supervisor.slots.ports` in `storm.yaml` to increase the number of workers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run multiple supervisors on a single host. Have a look at this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/jhwi1pOUakg) in storm-user mailing list.

> Just copy multiple Storm, and change the storm.yaml to specify
>   different ports for each supervisor(supervisor.slots.ports)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically possible - practically you may not need to do it - unless you are doing a PoC/Demo. I did this for one of the demo I gave by making multiple copies of storm and changing the ports for one of the supervisors - you can do it by changing supervisors.slots.ports.

Answer (score 1):

It is designed basically per node. So one node should have only one supervisor. This daemon deals with number of worker processes that you configured based on ports.

So there is no need of extra supervisor daemon per node.

Answer (score 0):

Supervisor is configured per node basis. Running multiple supervisor on a single node does not make much sense. The sole purpose of the `supervisor` daemon is to start/stop the worker process (each of these workers are responsible for running subset of topologies). From the doc page ..

> The supervisor listens for work assigned to its machine and starts and stops worker processes as necessary based on what Nimbus has assigned to it.